# html input element order

Tags: html

I have 2 labels and 2 radio button , and I want to lay them out as (label radio  label radio)

```
<label>Member</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="member" /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label>Company</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="company" />
```

but I get (label label radio radio )!
I changed it into `<br/>` and moved on, but still I want to know what's wrong !!!!

update:
css file contain

```
form label { 
display: block;
float: left; 
width: 150px; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 9px 0 0;
text-align: right; }

form input, form select {
margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
padding: 4px;
    float: left; }
```

I tried `for` attribute and it worked fine on google chrome& opera but not on IE

Comment: works as you wish on Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/KmDp8/

Comment: float each element to the left

Comment: it is better to have the input inside the label. IE users will be able to click on the label and activate the radio button. Styling will be easier as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KmDp8/) works on Firefox, you should probably try with a `for` attribute:

```
<form>
  <label for="Member">Member</label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="Member" />
  <br />
  <label for="Company">Company</label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="Company" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks alot . 'for' worked on chrome & opera but not on IE.it's not nessecary , but is there any way to fix that . thanks again.

Comment: you can try to apply Emil's comment: `it is better to have the input inside the label`. I don't know if this is W3C compliant but that's a good idea I think.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work , it just inversed the problem (radio radio label label) .. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This can't happen without some CSS applied, probably

```
label { float: left; }
```

Could you provide a link to the problem or a jsfiddle?

edit: none of them should float:

```
label, input[type="radio"] {
  float: static;
}
```

or all of them:

```
label, input[type="radio"] {
  float: left;
}
```

but not part of them.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the web browser you're using, but when I tested your code sample in Firefox on Windows XP, everything looked as expected.

```
Member o Comoany o
```

Here's the tricky part, though: Some browsers are more lenient than others in displaying HTML the way we intend versus the way it's supposed to be. I'm sure you're aware of all of that already, but sometimes we run into issues anyway.

Some things to consider:

1) The chosen DOCTYPE which makes some web browsers expect strict adherence to the way we write tags and such.

2) Sometimes, certain web browsers expect form elements to be within a form.

3) A label is typically tied to the corresponding form element. In your case, that would be something like:

```
<label for="Member">Member</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="Member" value="member" />
```

4) And the CSS. Are you using a CSS reset file? In that case, find out what the label CSS is. Or write your own label CSS and determine how you want it to be laid out (inline, block, float, etc.)

Here's some additional information:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

I hope that helps.

Comment: first of all they are in a form ! along with 10 other elements , I just posted the ones causing the trouble .CSS was set for both elements and 'for' worked on chrome & opera but not on IE . I don't get your point on DOCTYPE though . thanks for your help :)

Comment: Which version of IE and on which OS?

Comment: OK...does it work in any other browsers on your system? The DOCTYPE comment refers to the "for" attribute, since the DTD indicates in which HTML 4.01/XHTML 1.0 DTD the "for" attribute is allowed. In this case: S=Strict, T=Transitional, and F=Frameset.